# Shipping address and onestep checkout

Tags: shipping-address, onestepcheckout

[image: Firefox console]

I've got some problems with onestep checkout.

After filling both billing and shipping address I got an error (without message) and the process end.

How can I debug this problem?
I only read "error: true" in console.

Comment: look in your magento logs in /var/log to see if it provides any clues to the error.

Answer (score 1):

I enabled logging and discovered that there was a bad check on the shipping phone field. Thanks for your support